# Will these rules hold for multi-sets (bags)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

[image]

I have proved that RHS = LHS, but I don't know whether that is what is being asked, or htey want something else. For example, for No. 2, I have proved the relationship like;

$$
\begin{split}
(R\cup S)-T&=(R\cup S)\cap T^c=(R\cap T^c)\cup(S\cap T^c)=(R-T)\cup(S-T)
\end{split}
$$

So does this mean the relationship is holding if they are bags? or do I need something different? How is thsi question solved if I haven't solved it...

Thanks

Comment: Does $A\setminus B = A\cap B^\complement$ hold for multisets? What would $B^\complement$ even mean in that setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commutative law for union holds for bags. Consider any candidate for membership in $R\cup S$ or $S\cup R$: if it appears $r$ times in $R$ and $s$ times in $S$, then it appears $r+s$ times in both $R\cup S$ and $S\cup R$. Thus, $R\cup S=S\cup R$.

However, it’s *not* always true that $(R\cup S)\setminus T=(R\setminus T)\cup(S\setminus T)$. Suppose that $R=\{1\}$, and $S=T=\{1,1\}$; then $R\cup S=\{1,1,1\}$, so $(R\cup S)\setminus T=\{1\}$, but

$$(R\setminus T)\cup(S\setminus T)=\varnothing\cup\varnothing=\varnothing\ne\{1\}\;.$$

For the third one, what if $R=T=\{1\}$, and $S=\{1,1\}$?

Note that you can’t really talk about complements. Suppose that the underlying set is $\{0,1\}$, so that each multiset of interest is some number of zeroes and some number of ones. What is the complement of $\{0\}$? Is it $\{1\}$? If so, what is the complement of $\{0,0\}$? The bags $\{0,0,1\}$ and $\{0,1,1,1\}$ are different, so they ought to have different complements; what on earth could those complements be?

One useful way to think about bags is in terms of multiplicity functions. If $B$ is a bag on an underlying set $S$ of objects, $\chi_B:S\to\Bbb Z_{\ge 0}$ is the function that says how many copies of each element of $S$ are in $B$. For instance, if $S=\{0,1\}$ and $B=\{0,1,1,1\}$, then $\chi_B(0)=1$ and $\chi_B(1)=3$. If $B$ and $C$ are bags on $S$, then for each $x\in S$ we have

$$\begin{align*}
\chi_{B\cup C}(x)&=\chi_B(x)+\chi_C(x)\;,\\
\chi_{B\cap C}(x)&=\min\{\chi_B(x),\chi_C(x)\}\;,\text{ and}\\
\chi_{B\setminus C}(x)&=\max\{\chi_B(x)-\chi_C(x),0\}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: This is useful information but I think am still going to struggle with the 2nd one and third one. Could you synthesize one of them for me, so that I see the reasoning behind

Comment: @user124627: Do you see that the examples that I gave really are counterexamples to the proposed laws? In other words, are you asking about the examples themselves, or are you asking how I came up with them?

Comment: Thankyou very much Mr. Brian Scott, this really helps a lot. Am gonna read the examples a lot more carefully

Comment: @user124627: You’re welcome. If you still have questions after you’ve thought about them, feel free to ask.